# Struggling on the easiest way to dynamically select/join values from a table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table of variables and values of which i will know which parametercodes to select. This table would change dynamically.

```
CREATE TABLE #TreatmentTableVariables (ParameterCode VARCHAR(64), Value varchar(64))
INSERT #TreatmentTableVariables  VALUES ('TripOriginLocationCode','BGY')
```

I then have another table called AnalyticsDW.Treatment, where there is a column called TripOriginLocationCode and I want to select those rows from AnalyticsDW.Treatment where TripOriginLocationCode = the value from #TreatmentTableVariables.

AnalyticsDW.Treatment has primarykey of TreatmentID.

So i was originally using dynamic SQL to select the columns of TreatmentID that are contained in the temp table

```
SELECT @Columns = SubString (  (  SELECT + ', ' +'t.' + QUOTENAME(Column_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
JOIN #TreatmentTableVariables  t ON c.COLUMN_NAME=t.ParameterCode
WHERE Table_name IN ('Treatment','TreatmentProduct') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='AnalyticsDW'
FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ), 1, 1000)
```

but I am struggling on how to do the same thing to only select the rows of AnalyticsDW.Treatment where the dynamic column equals the parmetercode from #TreatmentTableVariables and the Value from #TreatmentTableVariables equals the value of the observation for that particular column.

Sample AnalyticsDW.Treatment data:

```
Declare  AnalyticsDW.Treatment table
(
TreatmentID varchar(100),
TripOriginLocationCode varchar(100),
TripDestinationLocationCode varchar(100)
)

insert into AnalyticsDW.Treatment values
('1','BRG','SLC'),
('2','AHO','BRG')
```

Goal dataset:

```
Declare  @goal table
(
TripOriginLocationCode varchar(100)
)

insert into @goal values
('BRG')
```

Example on how I was selecting from a goal dataset (within a dynamic sql query):

```
declare @dynamicquery varchar(200)

set @dynamicquery='
select a.*, '+@Columns+' into #CompletePricingtypes2 from #somedataset a 
join AnalyticsDW.Treatment t on a.TreatmentID=t.TreatmentID '
```

Edit: additional info

```
declare
@whereConditions nvarchar(max) = stuff((
    -- here we create where conditions as
    --   paramCode in (itsValues) 
    --   or anotherParamCode in (anotherItsValues) etc.
    select
        'or ' + 'where ' +'t.' +ParameterCode + ' in ('+''''+ltrim([Values]) +''''+') '
    from (
        -- here we create output with two columns: parameter code and
        -- all values associated with that code separated by comma
        select
            t.ParameterCode,
            stuff((
                select
                    ', ' + [Value]
                from #TreatmentTableVariables
                where
                    ParameterCode in (t.ParameterCode)

                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as [Values]
        from #TreatmentTableVariables t
        where ParameterCode in (select COLUMN_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where  Table_name IN ('Treatment') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='AnalyticsDW')
    ) conditions
), 1, 3, '')
print @whereconditions
```

edit: this works

```
 select
    'or ' +   ParameterCode + ' in('+ [Values] +')
       '

    from (
 select distinct
            t.ParameterCode,

           (
                select
                    ', ''' + [Value] + ''''
                from #TreatmentTableVariables
                where
                    ParameterCode in (t.ParameterCode)

            ) as [Values]

        from #TreatmentTableVariables t
        where ParameterCode in (select 
                                COLUMN_name 
                                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
                                where  Table_name IN ('Treatment') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='AnalyticsDW')
        ) conditions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**. First, I forgot distinct in inner select.

Second, you're still trying to wrap whole `in` condition with single quotes. You need

```
or ParameterCode in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

, but you do it as

```
or ParameterCode in ('value1, value2, value3') -- look at quotes
```

Third, you put `where` to every `or` condition as

```
where ParameterCode1 in (...)
or where ParameterCode2 in (...)
or where ParameterCode3 in (...)
```

Remove it from `@whereCondition` string construction and complete your query as I do further in `@selectQuery` variable.

---

I think you can use real dynamic sql queries, i.e. build query dynamically and then execute it (look at comments in code snippet below for more info):

```
declare
    @whereConditions nvarchar(max) = stuff((
    -- here we create where conditions as
    --   paramCode in (itsValues) 
    --   or anotherParamCode in (anotherItsValues) etc.
    select
        'or ' + ParameterCode + ' in (' + [Values] + ') 
        '
    from (
        -- here we create output with two columns: parameter code and
        -- all values associated with that code separated by comma
        select distinct
            t.ParameterCode,
            stuff((
                select
                    ', ''' + [Value] + ''''
                from #TreatmentTableVariables
                where
                    ParameterCode in (t.ParameterCode)
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as [Values]
        from #TreatmentTableVariables t
        where ParameterCode in (
            select 
                COLUMN_name 
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
            where
                table_name = 'Treatment'
                and table_schema ='AnalyticsDW'
        )
    ) conditions
    FOR XML PATH ('') -- !!! this one
), 1, 3, '')

declare
    @selectQuery nvarchar(max) = N'
select
    *
from AnalyticsDW.Treatment
where
    ' + @whereConditions

print @selectQuery
exec sp_executesql @selectQuery
```

Comment: Great, works well at least as a basis. Thanks. One question, in the  select
            'or ' + ParameterCode + ' in (' + [Values] + ') ' how could I adjust it so the value has quotes around it? I have been trying to adjust it but keep getting mostly [Values] as a string instead of the [Value] inside quotes.

Comment: @AdamSanders, you're welcome! Take a look at updated query version. You need to wrap every single [Value] with quotes, i.e. do it in inner select. As you see, I added `'` before `[Value]` and after (had to escape it so it's doubled as `''`).

Comment: Got it, one other question. I am not sure what to adjust when there may be more than one ParameterCode to pull from #TreatmentTableVariables. if there is one value I have it working, but if I add another, it says "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: updated my query and added clarification to the post

Comment: I get what you are saying, but for some reason using the new code still gives me the same error.

Comment: It seems to come from when I make it into @whereConditions nvarchar(max) and add all the stuff/xml code. If I take all that out it works

Comment: ohh, I forgot second `for xml path ('')` :) Sorry for all that bugs)